# Run Magento Product Alerts more than once a day

Tags: magento, product, alerts

Is it possible to run Magento's product alerts more than once per day?
I'm running v1.4.0.1 and the frequency options found in System>Config>Catalog>Product Alerts Run Settings only goes down to Daily.

I would like to run it hourly if possible?

Anyone able to tell me how I can do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you start looking at his source model ... `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Cron_Frequency` .... in there you can see those 3 constants ... you would have rewrite it and add another constant say  const CRON_HOURLY  = 'H';

and than you would have to rewrite/modify the following `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Product_Alert_Cron` to build the cron expression accordingly :)

Altough I have never done this exact thing myself I think this puts you on the right track

HTH :)

Comment: Thanks! Can this be done in an over-ride file to avoid issues with upgrades later? Do I just recreate those two files in my local folder with the correct paths, or is it more involved than that?

Comment: I believe you should be able to rewrite both classes in normal way using xml. Creating same directory/file in local folder is ill adviced by Magento